# Msbuild error: failed to start monitoring file changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild

when i run Msbuild web.csproj i get the following error:

> AfterBuild target> ->  C:..\web\obj\debug\csautoparameterize\original\web.config
>   : error ASPconfig: an error occurred
>   loading a configuration file:
>   Directory C:..\web\obj\debug\csautoparameterize\original\Configs'
>   does not exist.  Fail to start
>   monitoring file changes.

if i open visual studio (2010)..clean solution and rebuild, its fine.  if i try to do publish via visual studio, this error returns and i cant build again (until i clean solution).

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem... I have some config files in a folder called "Config" and the error from msbuild is the same

Comment: If you found a permanent solution, let me know... Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here... Code on the C: drive of a Parallels virtual machine. Anybody found a permanent solution?

Comment: I have this problem too. Any ideas?

Comment: I have this problem too. Any luck?

Comment: @nologo did you found the solution

Comment: sorry guys, a long time ago. no update from me

Answer (score 2):

Is that a network drive? I was getting a similar error when I had my SVN working copy on a network drive, apparently the folder monitoring service for the test server completely freaks out when it's not a physical drive.

Comment: nope..local C: if i run msbuild after a clean it works..run it a 2nd time..i get the error.

Comment: wonder if my svn directory is busted..will get delete and get latest

Comment: Moving the source to a local drive fixed it for me